# How to disable the clicked button on a repeat list using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, repeater

I have a code that disables a button when clicking on it, this works, but it's disabling all the buttons I have on the screen.

This is the part of code,
I'm using class components:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: false };
  }
  
  
  handleFile(file) {
    const id = file.id; // maybe I can use this id?
    
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    if (document.statusCode == 200) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    } 
  }


  _renderButton(text, props) {
    const isFile = (props.type.toLowerCase() === 'file');
    return (
      <Row>
        {isFile && (
          <Button disabled={this.state.isLoading} onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); this.handleFile(props)}} />
        )}
      </Row>
    );
  }
```

How can I disable just the clicked button using react? How to use the map in this situation?

Comment: You should add the code where you're adding the rest of the buttons. You're not doing anything with that id in `handleFile`.

Comment: @Andy 
Yes, I know, I put it as an example, is there a way to use this id to trigger the button?

Answer (score 1):

Give each button [an id data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and use state to register whether that button has been clicked, and if it has disable it on the next render.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [id]: true });
  }

  createButtons() {
    const jsx = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const button = <button
        data-id={i}
        disabled={this.state[i]}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >Click me {i}
      </button>;
      jsx.push(button);
    }
    return jsx;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.createButtons()}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
button:disabled { color: red; opacity: 50%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```